# Join 2 Tables Together - Add Values and Group By Certain ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wanting to add together the opportunity values and group them by assigned_by_id in table two where the company_id in table one matches the id in table two.  A little more detail:

**Table One**

```
ID, COMPANY_ID, OPPORTUNITY, DATE_CREATE
```

**Table Two**

```
ID,ASSIGNED_BY_ID
```

What I am trying to do is add all the values in OPPORTUNITY for each ASSIGNED_ID.  COMPANY_ID in **table one** is the same as ID in **table two**.

So for example:

**Table One**

```
COMPANY_ID | OPPORTUNITY | DATE_CREATE 
1000       | 50          | 2013/09/19
1000       | 100         | 2013/09/18
1000       | 200         | 2013/09/18
1005       | 100         | 2013/09/18
1005       | 200         | 2013/09/18
```

**Table Two**

```
ID         | ASSIGNED_BY_ID 
1000       | 4
1000       | 4
1000       | 4
1005       | 2
1005       | 2
```

So I want a SELECT statement that will provide these results:

```
ASSIGNED_BY_ID  | OPPORTUNITY
4               | 350
2               | 300
```

I would like individual select statements per ASSIGNED_BY_ID.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.Assigned_By_ID, SUM(a.OPPORTUNITY )
FROM    tbOne a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT ID, Assigned_By_ID
            FROM    tnTwo
        ) b ON a.COMPANY_ID = b.ID
GROUP   BY b.Assigned_By_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ad5aa/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ASSIGNED_BY_ID ║ OPPORTUNITY ║
╠════════════════╬═════════════╣
║              2 ║         300 ║
║              4 ║         350 ║
╚════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to just get the opportunity sum value where assigned_by_id = 2.  I just need the opportunity value as I will be printing it out using php so I don't need the table.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use this in a php query I need an AS in the statement so that I can call the number, would you know where this would go?

Comment: in this fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ad5aa/5, you can call `$row['OPPORTUNITY']`

Comment: Awesome! Yes, that worked.  One last question.  If I wanted to bring in a WHERE DATE_CREATE BETWEEN '2013/09/18' AND '2013/09/19' which is in table one would this be possible? Thank you already for the input on this! Much appreciated